# Dynamically setting Width and Height on Camera.MAUI component

Tags: xaml, camera, maui

I'm trying to create a custom ContentView. The view contains both the frontfacing, and backfacing camera.
The Backfacing camera needs to fill the entire screen, while the frontfacing camera is floating in the top left.

However, using WidthRequest and HeightRequest doesn't seem very dynamic for supporting different screensizes.
I'm having issues figuring out how to use the full screen instead, and perhaps use percentages to calculate the size for the frontfacing camera and shutter button.

Here's my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:cv="clr-namespace:Camera.MAUI;assembly=Camera.MAUI"
         x:Class="App.Components.Camera">
<Grid>
    <Frame CornerRadius="10"
            ZIndex="1000"
            WidthRequest="100" 
            HeightRequest="150" 
            VerticalOptions="Start" 
            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
            Margin="10">
        <Grid 
            WidthRequest="100" 
            HeightRequest="150">
            <cv:CameraView 
                x:Name="FrontCameraView" 
                CamerasLoaded="FrontCameraLoaded"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>

    <Grid 
        ZIndex="900" 
        WidthRequest="500" 
        HeightRequest="700">
        <cv:CameraView 
            x:Name="BackCameraView" 
            CamerasLoaded="BackCameraLoaded"/>
    </Grid>

    <Grid ZIndex="1000" 
          WidthRequest="100" 
          HeightRequest="75" 
          VerticalOptions="End" 
          HorizontalOptions="Center" 
          Margin="20">
        <ImageButton 
            Source="../Resources/Images/camera_shutter_circle.svg"
            Clicked="SnapImages"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: You could use an [AbsoluteLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/absolutelayout) for proportional positioning and sizing without using values for `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`. With that you can have the main camera sort of "full screen", i.e. filling the entire available space of the page and then overlay the buttons and front-facing camera. Another way would be to setup a specific Grid layout that resembles the relative positioning and sizing of your page and then use The `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` attached attributes for position and size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm having issues figuring out how to use the full screen instead, and
> perhaps use percentages to calculate the size for the frontfacing
> camera and shutter button.

The `GridLength` struct of `Grid` specifies a row height or a column width in terms of the `GridUnitType` enumeration, which has three members:

- Absolute – the row height or column width is a value in
  device-independent units (a number in XAML).
- Auto – the row height or column width is autosized based on the cell
  contents (Auto in XAML).
- **Star** – leftover row height or column width is allocated
  proportionally (a number followed by * in XAML).

So, you can use `*` to allocate the leftover row height or column width for your view.

Besides, you can also attribute `Grid.RowSpan` and `Grid.ColumnSpan` of `Grid` reasonably to achieve the effect you want.

For more information, you can check document: [Rows and columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/grid#rows-and-columns).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I tried doing this before, but I noticed that I messed up, since my parent layout was a VerticalStackLayout. Changing this to Grid aswell, fixed my issue. And the Star helped with filling the entire page out.